# Android Opengles CameraPreview (Draw text on camera feed)

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, android-camera

I'd like to have something like a "toast", at the bottom of the camera preview. I can give you an example of what I mean, just take a look at this image:

http://www.lemacinaie.it/amiata/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/realta_aumentata.jpg

I'd like to achieve the same thing, Im able to bind the camerapreview in a GLSurfaceView, but I don't know how to draw a box with text inside it, just like a toast, in the onDrawFrame method. Can anyone give some hints? Thank you.

Comment: for this you can simply use a view you display on top

Comment: yeah i know... and that is what im doing but i'd like to use opengl es since it is more efficient and powerful... just can't find a way to draw the text using opengl es... any hint would be appreciate.

Comment: You really shouldn't use an OpenGL view just to draw text. OpenGL has no text drawing support, and the best you can really do is to just draw characters out of a bitmap, which probably looks a lot worse than whatever normal text view you can use.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to display a polygon with a 2D bitmap texture.

You create the bitmap from a view with such kind of code:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
bitmapTexture = Bitmap.createBitmap(params.width, params.height,
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmapTexture);
v.layout(0, 0, params.width, params.height);
v.draw(canvas);
```

So you can build your view exactly as you would do without opengl, then draw it on a canvas to get the corresponding bitmap.